# The particle never reaches which point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A particle starts at origin and moves in such a way that the velocity
>   at the point (x,0) is given by the formula
>   $\frac{dx}{dt}=\cos^2(\pi x)$.Then the particle never reaches the point on?
>
> $(A)x=1/4$  $\space$   $(B)x=3/4$    $\space$         $(C)x=1/2$   $\space$    $(D)x=1$

I could'nt understand what the problem is actually wanting.Could someone tell me the necessary approach?

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a typo in your formula, should be $\frac{dx}{dt} = \cos^2(\color{red}{\pi}x)$. The answer is $C$ because $\lim_{L \to \frac12^{-}} \int_0^L \frac{dx}{\cos^2(\pi x)} = \infty$ because the integrand has a non-integrable singularity near $x \approx \frac12$.

Comment: "Then the particle never reaches the point on?" Is this really the original wording? If the particle never reaches $x=1/2$, say, then it also never reaches $x=3/4$ or $x=1$. It should be something like "Which of these is the smallest $x$ that is never reached by the particle?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solving the equation gives
$$
\begin{align}
t
&=\int_0^x\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\cos^2(\pi u)}\\
&=\int_0^x\sec^2(\pi u)\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{\tan(\pi x)}\pi
\end{align}
$$
That is,
$$
x=\frac{\arctan(\pi t)}\pi
$$
Thus, $x$ starts at $0$ and moves toward, but never reaches, $\frac12$. Therefore, of the given points, $x$ can only reach $\frac14$, the other points will never be reached.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the differential equation and you will get $\tan \pi x = \pi t + \pi c$ and using initial value condition, $x=0$ at $t=0$, you have $c=0$.

So $\tan \pi x = \pi t$ is the equation of motion of particle.
Now the particle will never reach the points where the equation of its motion is not defined. So you know the points of discontinuity of $\tan \pi x$.

Your job now for this problem is to see what values given in the option satisfy this condition.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

By integrating with BC we get

$$ \tan \pi x = \pi t $$

It takes infinite time to reach $ x=\frac12.$

So, all  $$ x > =\frac12 $$

are unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation is Lipschitz, thus uniqueness applies.

The stationary points of the ODE are at $\cos(πx)=0$, that is, at $x=\frac12+k$, $k\in \Bbb Z$. Because of uniqueness, no solution can cross or even reach the constant solutions at these stationary points, the solution through the origin stays inside the interval $(-\frac12,\frac12)$.